# TCPDF print formatted text

Tags: php, html, pdf, moodle

I added `print` function for the `course` `information` in `Moodle`. Using the `TCPDF` `library` and `javascript`, it prints the following from the `$description` `variable`:

> Course Visibility and Sorting
>   Instructors The «courses» will be sorted first by availability (courses that have been made available to students will show up first followed by courses not available to students), then by semester.   For example, if you are teaching a course in the current semester and it is available to students, it will appear at the top of your course listing.  If you are teaching a course in the current semester and it is not available to students, it will appear after all the courses that are available to students.
>   Students first year students second year students post graduate

Note, that `«courses»` comes with the original formating in the `pdf`!

Here is the code I use in `printpdf.php`:

```
$html = '<html>
<body>
<img src="/moodle/theme/base/pix/logo.png" alt="test alt attribute" border="0" height="100" width="220" allign="left" /><br />
<p><span style="font-size: small;"><font color="#######">Organisation name<br><b>Directorate <br><b>Department </b><br>Subdepartment</font></span></p>
<h2>Course Information</h2>
<h3>'. $title . '</h3><br />
'. $description . '<br />
</body>
</html>';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('CourseInfo.pdf', 'D');
```

Is it possible, to print it in the original format as on the page with `$description`:

**Course Visibility and Sorting**

**Instructors:** The «courses» will be sorted first by availability (courses that have been made available to students will show up first followed by courses not available to students), then by semester.   For example, if you are teaching a course in the current semester and it is available to students, it will appear at the top of your course listing.  If you are teaching a course in the current semester and it is not available to students, it will appear after all the courses that are available to students.

**Students:**

- first year students
- second year students
- post graduate

Answer (score 0):

you can change the `$description` variable that you are passing to `printpdf.php` in a html way.

```
<h2>Course Visibility and Sorting</h2>

 <p>Instructors: The «courses» will be sorted first by availability (courses     
that have been made available to students will show up first followed by courses     
not available to students), then by semester. For example, if you are teaching a     
course in the current semester and it is available to students, it will 
appear at the top of your course listing. If you are teaching a course in      
the current semester and it is not available to students, it will appear 
after all the courses that are available to students. </p>

<h2>Students:</h2>
<br>

first year students<br>
second year students<br>
post graduate<br>
```

Comment: It is user generated text and trough the variable is passed every time differently formated html. I used `$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, $description."", 0, 'J', 0, 0, '' ,'', true);` and got at least the different ligning of the text. What I am missing are characters like bullets etc.

Comment: replace the bullets with php function `str_replace()` to something that tcpdf allows.